# How can I drag a file to an exe I create (drag and drop over the Icon) and have it as an argument when the exe start running?

Tags: c#

how can I drag a file to an exe I create (drag and drop over the Icon) and have it as an argument when the exe start running ?

Answer (score 2):

If you make this following code, then when you drag your file onto the exe icon, the args[0] will have the path of it as an argument:
 (I added the if statement that if you start the program without dragging anything
 it shouldn't crash)

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```